# Unable to use End At in search for Firebase Admin With Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, desktop-application, firebase-admin

I am trying to perform a Firebase Query, am using python and firebase-admin, using only startAt brings no results, adding end at throws the error shown below. Thanks for any guidance.

Query

```
 self.users = self.ref.child("products").order_by_child(chosenCriteria).start_at(searchWord).endAt(searchWord+"\uf8ff").get()
```

Error

```
 self.users = self.ref.child("products").order_by_child(chosenCriteria).start_at(searchWord).endAt(searchWord+"\uf8ff").get()
 AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'endAt'
```

Answer (score 0):

This reference has helped me, I have had to restructure my queries, though am still not certain why it didn't work the above way

https://morioh.com/p/a593f973aff0